# How to display buffer pdf from mongodb in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

**  I am not able to display the pdf after retrieving it from the MongoDB in reactjs after get request. Can someone help me?
I have stored the pdf file in the MongoDB with the use of multer, now I am want it to display it in the new tab in the reactjs, but don't know how to write src.
**

````
const storage2 = multer.memoryStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "folder1/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage2,
});
app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.file);
  if (!req.file.buffer) {
    console.log('not uploaded');
  } else {
    // console.log(req.body)
    const imageDocument = new images({ image: req.file.buffer ,Subject:'Automata'});
    imageDocument
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("Image document saved:");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error saving image document:", error);
      });
    res.send("OK");
  }
}); ```
````